# Data not etching using Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch some fruits using an API and displaying them into different components using axios. Problem is, it is not working. The data is not displaying and I am not getting any records on the console. Here is what I have done, and I am using Context API for this one.

Fruits Data File

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ApiContext from './ApiContext';

function FruitsData(props) {
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

const fetchFruits = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/fruits');
    setFruits(response.fruits);
    console.log(response.fruits)
}

const selectItem = (id) => {
    const fruit = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.id === id);
    setSelectedItem(fruit);
}

const fetchItem = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/fruit/${id}`);
    setSelectedItem(response.fruit);
}

return (
    <ApiContext.Provider value={[fruits, setFruits, selectedItem, selectItem, fetchFruits, fetchItem ]}>
        {props.children}
    </ApiContext.Provider>
);
}

export default FruitsData;
```

The Component to display the Fruits

```
import ApiContext from '../../contexts/ApiContext';

function Training() {
let navigate = useNavigate();
const [fruits, setFruits] = useContext(ApiContext);

return (
    <div>
   {fruits && fruits.map((fruit) => (
   <FruitWidget fruit={fruit} key={fruit.id} />
    ))}
    </div>
);
}
export default Training;
```

App.js

```
 <FruitsData>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="training" element={<Training />} />
          <Route path="fruit-details/:fruitId" element={<FruitDetails />} />
        </Routes>
      </FruitsData>
```

Answer (score 0):

will be honest. did not read your code, you already said - have nothing on console it means your URL is not correct

```
const fetchFruits = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/fruits'); // problem is here :)
    setFruits(response.fruits);
    console.log(response.fruits)
}
```